# How to achieve clean Topology at joining edge of dissimilar features?

Tags: modeling, topology

How can this topology be improved? Multiple attempts and several hours later, I have failed to create a successful all-quad mesh again. I keep trying to visualize face loops that define the edges I need on this object (a screw), but it is very difficult to join these dissimilar sections of geometry together. I have been watching tutorials/speed modelling sessions in an attempt to gain some further insight.

I am guessing that the round part needs to be spherical-ish, because if the verts are not distributed evenly, then it will appear lumpy instead of round/smooth...though clearly, the perimeter loop where the plus shaped area meets the round part has not-evenly-distributed verts all along that edge...

I tried to join the two edges and redistribute the verts to make them spherical, but it looks terrible. Here was that attempt (notice that the ridge is wavy and uneven...), I abandoned this approach after it seemed to be a lost cause:

[image: topology travesty 1, horrible wavy edge]

And here is a later attempt, the round part is a bit lumpy/not-smooth...I also realized that there was a triangle here later on too (how would someone fix that? start completely over, since adding geometry would change the number of verts at the joining edge between the two surfaces?):

[image: topology travesty 2, lumpy surface with overlooked triangle]

Comment: you can select in edit mode and scale x to 0

Comment: The joining edge is intended to not be flat. It should be in the shape of a plus sign/cross, but shrink wrapped in the z direction to the surface of the spherical/dome shaped part.

Comment: Can you post the .blend file? Also, a paintover image indicate the surfaces/profile you DO want would be helpful as well.

Comment: Of course you can choose to devote time to minimize triangles and maximize quads.  May I ask why that is a concern here?  Will the object be highly animated with close up views?  The UV sphere and Cone have triangles.

Comment: The restriction to not allow triangles might be unfounded, if the Screw isn't being deformed and has nice smoothing then it's not likely to matter -- but you might have that one edge case when it does (if so elaborate..)

Comment: I want all quads in part as an exercise in creating all quad topology, which I'm terrible at solving topology problems for (less critical for this particular form than for others), and in part for subsurfing. One of the main points is to get better at creating the proper/needed edge/face loops for a given form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Blender most of us would not model a screw by joining two separate meshes, one for the curvature and the other for the groove.

Other 3d packages such as AutoCAD / SolidWorks (and free alternatives) have a different internal representation of shapes. That's why boolean 'carving' is great for those kinds of programs. In those packages geometry remains a mathematical entity until converted to *mesh-geometry* for export.

In Blender we use mesh geometry (verts, edges, faces) all the way, and that means a different approach is worth considering. You've noticed that trying to match up two very different sections of mesh can be quite a  hassle.

#### Proportional Editing to the rescue!

I'd go for geometry roughly similar to this.

[image]

And the use Proportional Edition, move, to push the upper verts into that nice curve. Getting a dome curvature is the smaller problem with this kind of geometry. The biggest issue is thinking ahead about where you want sharp corners and you can do that as a flat surface first and extrude parts down later.

Enable *proportional editing* and press G to start moving, and Z to exclude the XY movement. Use Shift+Mouse wheel to adjust the sphere of influence. See [the manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional) for more information about proportional editing
[image].

The outcome: (with some corrections to the base)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

- Above and below all quads with a shrink wrap.

[image]

[image]

- Please beware of impure and unchaste images below.
- Consider a boolean modifier A difference B. Sphere minus Cross Sign. You may have already done this.  The cross sign has a bevel modifier.

[image]

- Press Apply.  You may use a higher resolution sphere (more vertices) for a sharper result.

Comment: OP wants **clean topology**, in this case I think your answer is a bit off.

Comment: Boolean modifiers generate **extra geometry**, which is hard to control and especially not **clean**. To undestand what I mean, see: http://forums.newtek.com/showthread.php?98754-Polygon-Table-Help-Building-One. Maybe mention that this is an alternative (fast) way of creating a screw. In addition, I would suggest using the boolean model as **base for retopology**, which makes sense in many cases to be more flexible in the design process.